# Issue with transfer of domain from Google to AWS

Tags: amazon-route53

I have transferred my domain from Google to AWS 7 days back. The transfer process has been completed in AWS. I have created a public hosted zone in Router 53 and the NS records present in Route 53 are matching with the NS records of my domain in AWS. Also created CNAME records pointed to the application load balancer.

I am able to access my domain inside AWS workspace and even dig command returns the results in my AWS workspace but not working in some machines outside of AWS workspace but when I use load balancer url, I am able to access the application so there are no issues with security group configuration.

Also no dig results when using this url https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/

Am I missing something here? Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved after disabling the DNSSEC in Route 53. I think I had not disabled DNSSEC in google before transferring the domain to AWS so it has transferred the DNSSEC with keys to AWS.